# GradleException: Android tasks have already been created for multi module shared versions

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-module

Trying to follow [Jeroen Mols modularization sample](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2019/06/12/modularizationtips/), he specifies a nice technique to allow all modules to share version numbers. In the top level project build.gradle, add this:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty('android')) {

            android {
                compileSdkVersion build_versions.target_sdk

                defaultConfig {
                    minSdkVersion build_versions.min_sdk
                    targetSdkVersion build_versions.target_sdk
                    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

                    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
                }

                compileOptions {
                    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now any module level build.gradle files do not need to specify these fields. However I get:

`GradleException: Android tasks have already been created.`

I am not specifying  android.applicationVariants, android.libraryVariants or android.testVariants like the description to this error mentions so what could I be doing wrong here? I have even tried removing the android block from every module completely and the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue was that I created a libraries module *inside* a core module instead of the same folder level. My guess is this `afterEvaluate` android block doesn't work for modules inside modules. So my solution was just to make sure that modules are specified at the same level.